# Edit Command in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am extracting data from database in gridview, where I have given a link button "Edit" for editing the data of that row. However while editing , one of the columns(YEAR) of my gridview becomes a dropdown list. While fetching the data from database, the Column "Year" consists of label and in edit mode it gets changed to dropdownlist. Moreover I added a condition to make the link buttons appear/disappear based on the value of the Label "Year". When I edit the particular row it throws an error because as soon as edit command is called it converts the column into dropdownlist however the row_databound searches for label.  It shows "Object not set to an instance....." PLease help

Aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnRowDataBound="gv1_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="gv1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="tid" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="694px">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr No">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tid" SortExpression="tid" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tid") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="category">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("category") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnlist" runat="server"><asp:ListItem Text="Soft Skills"></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Text="Technical Skills"></asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Announced at" SortExpression="dt">                     
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblDt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dt", "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm tt}") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="year">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyr" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblyr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("year") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Id" SortExpression="userid">                     
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("userid") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                        
             <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="btndel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return isConfirm()" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>                                               

                        <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnmail" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return isConfirm()" Text="Send Mail" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>--%>

                      </ItemTemplate>                       
             </asp:TemplateField>           
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdte" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                     &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="btncncl" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>            
             <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnmail" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return isConfirm()" Text="Send Mail" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>                  
            </Columns> 
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="#99CCCC" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

c#

```
 protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            Label lbly = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblyr");
            if (lbly.Text == DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() || lbly.Text == ((DateTime.Now.Year)-1).ToString())
            {

                LinkButton btedt = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnedit");
                LinkButton btdel = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btndel");
                LinkButton btsm = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnmail");
                btdel.Visible = true;
                btedt.Visible = true;
                btsm.Visible = true;

            }
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0) {
                RadioButtonList rbtnlist = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rbtnlist");                  
                DropDownList ddlist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlyr");
                for (int i = (DateTime.Now.Year); i >= ((DateTime.Now.Year)-1) ; i--)
                {
                    ddlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
                }

                ddlist.DataBind();
                rbtnlist.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: why don't you use the drop down list in both modes? edit and view? or you need to use both?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are binding your grid with a DataTable with colum name "Year". Try below code where dt refers to your Datatable:

```
    protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int rowno = e.Row.DataItemIndex;
            //Suppose dt is DataTable to which you are binding your grid
            //and year is the column name within this datatable
            string year = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["year"]);
            if (year == DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() || year == ((DateTime.Now.Year) - 1).ToString())
            {

                LinkButton btedt = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnedit");
                LinkButton btdel = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btndel");
                LinkButton btsm = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnmail");
                btdel.Visible = true;
                btedt.Visible = true;
                btsm.Visible = true;

            }
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                RadioButtonList rbtnlist = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rbtnlist");
                DropDownList ddlist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlyr");
                for (int i = (DateTime.Now.Year); i >= ((DateTime.Now.Year) - 1); i--)
                {
                    ddlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
                }

                ddlist.DataBind();
                rbtnlist.DataBind();
            }
        }
```